# Confusion in the proof of $(-\infty,\limsup_{n}x_{n})\subseteq\limsup(-\infty, x_{n})\subseteq(-\infty,\limsup_{n}x_{n}]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, analysis

I am trying to solve the following exercise from A. N. Shiryaev Probability 1 Page 139 Exercise 8. It states the following:

> Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers and $A_{n}=(-\infty, x_{n})$. Define $x:=\limsup x_{n}$ and $A_{n}:=\limsup A_{n}$. Then, $$(-\infty, x)\subseteq A\subseteq (-\infty,x].$$

In other words, $A$ is either $(-\infty,x)$ or $(-\infty,x]$, and $A=(-\infty,x]$ if and only if $x\in A$ (looks a little bit tautological but it actually confuses me).

---

I have proved $(-\infty,x)\subseteq A$, as follows. Let $t\in (-\infty, x)$. Then $t<\limsup x_{n}$. Suppose that $t\notin A$ so that $t\in\liminf A_{n}^{c}$, i.e. there exists $n_{0}\geq 1$ such that $t\geq x_{k}$ for all $k\geq n_{0}$. It then implies that $t\geq\sup_{k\geq n_{0}}x_{k}$, which means that $t\geq\inf_{n}\sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}$, contradicting the hypothesis that $t<\limsup x_{n}$. Hence, $t\in A$ must hold, and thus $(-\infty, x)\subseteq A$.

---

To prove $A\subseteq (-\infty, x])$, if $t\in A$ such that $t\neq x$, then for all $n\geq 1$, there exists $k=k(n)\geq n$ such that $t<x_{k}$. Hence, for all $n\geq 1$, we have $t<x_{k}\leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}$, and thus $t<\inf_{n}\sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}$, which implies that $t<x$.

However, I got stuck at an indescribable confusion. Why does the above proof not apply in the case of $t=x$? Does it really matter if $t=x$ or not? The proof above seems not using any fact related to $t\neq x$. Hence, I believe that the confusion comes down to the following two questions:

a) why is it possible for $x\in A$ anyways? If $x\in A$, it means that $x<x_{n}$ infinitely often. I can imagine a sitution where $x_{n}\searrow x$ or a tail sequence of $(x_{n})$ decreases to $x$, then indeed $x<x_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.

b) So, it gives me another question, is there any conditions on the sequence $(x_{n})$ so that $x<x_{n}$ infinitely often? Is it true that $x<x_{n}$ infinitely oftern if and only if $x_{n}\searrow x$ (or a tail sequence decreases to $x$)?

Comment: I am not sure what "tail sequence" means to you, but I assume $x + \frac1n\sin n$ or $x+\frac1n(-1)^n$ would be illustrative.

Comment: @BrianMoehring by "tail sequence" i mean that throwing away the first finitely many of $x_{n}$s, it will become a decreasing sequence to $x$.

Comment: Then no, for both limsup and liminf, the key objects of discussion are more generally subsequences, and tail sequences aren't sufficient.

Comment: @BrianMoehring how does the subsequence $x_{n}$ affect set sequence $(-\infty, x_{n})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t\neq x$, since $\limsup_{n}x_{n}$ is the largest accumulation points (the largest subsequential limit), then we must have $t<\limsup_{n}x_{n}\iff t<x_{n}\ \text{i.o.}\iff t\in\limsup_{n}(-\infty, x_{n}).$ (The key here is that $t<x_{n}\ \text{i.o.}$ does not necessarily imply that $t<\limsup_{n}x_{n}$, since $t$ can equal to $\limsup_{n}x_{n}$.) Hence, if $x\notin A$, then $t\in A\iff t\in(-\infty, x)$, and thus $A=(-\infty,x)$. If $x\in A$, then since we have $x\neq t\in A\iff t\in (0,x)$, it follows that $A=(-\infty, x)\cup \{x\}=(-\infty, x]$. Hence, $A$ is either $(-\infty, x)$ or $(-\infty, x]$, depending on if $\limsup_{n}x_{n}<x_{k}$ i.o.